# $Project is not working with $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I had two csv files Emp and Product which I imported in mongo. `ProductID` is common in both the files.

The Question is: Find the Product name `PName` from Product Collection which is used by `Manish1`.

According to the question I have to join both the Collection to print the Product Name.

My Answer is this:

```
db.Emp.aggregate([

{"$match":{"Ename":"Manish1"}},

 {"$lookup":{"from":"Product","localField":"ProductID","foreignField":"ProductID","as":"ProductName"}},
 
 {$project:{"PName":1,"_id":0}}

]).pretty()
```

and the output I am getting is: `{ }`

if I change `"_id": 1` or don't mention the `_id` I am getting id as output .

I don't know Why I am not getting the desired Output

Help me to solve it.

Comment: Thats default, always `_id` will be in the document. If you dont need, as you used, use _id:0

Comment: I know it but when i did _id:0 the output is { }

Comment: can you provide some sample data